# How to get values in json using procedural instead of PDO

Tags: php

sorry for asking this question but im beginner in PHP/MYSQLi, i need some help in my project who make in PDO style but currently im not familiar with PDO, so i need the below code in procedural style using while loop. Thanks

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["id"])){
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE id='".$_POST["id"]."'";
$statement = $connect->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
$programming_languages = '';
$name = '';
foreach($result as $row){
    $name = $row["name"];
    $language_array = explode(",", $row["programming_languages"]);
    $count = 1;
    foreach($language_array as $language){
        $button = '';
        if($count > 1){
            $button = '<button type="button" name="remove" id="'.$count.'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove">x</button>';
        }else{
            $button = '<button type="button" name="add_more" id="add_more" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">+</button>';
        }
        $programming_languages .= '
        <tr id="row'.$count.'">
        <td><input type="text" name="programming_languages[]" placeholder="Add Programming Languages" class="form-control name_list" value="'.$language.'" /></td>
        <td align="center">'.$button.'</td>
        </tr>
        ';
        $count++;
    }
}
$output = array(
    'name'     => $name,
    'programming_languages' => $programming_languages
);
echo json_encode($output);
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to figure it out and hope this will help you.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if(isset($_POST["id"])){
    $programming_languages = '';
    $name = '';
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE id='".$_POST["id"]."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    // check if total records greater than zero
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $name = $row["name"];
        $language_array = explode(",", $row["programming_languages"]);
        $count = 1;
        foreach($language_array as $language){
            $button = '';
            if($count > 1){
                $button = '<button type="button" name="remove" id="'.$count.'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove">x</button>';
            }else{
                $button = '<button type="button" name="add_more" id="add_more" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">+</button>';
            }
            $programming_languages .= '
            <tr id="row'.$count.'">
            <td><input type="text" name="programming_languages[]" placeholder="Add Programming Languages" class="form-control name_list" value="'.$language.'" /></td>
            <td align="center">'.$button.'</td>
            </tr>
            ';
            $count++;
            }
        }
        $output = array(
            'name'     => $name,
            'programming_languages' => $programming_languages
        );
        echo json_encode($output);
    } else {
    // no record in table
        echo "0 results";
    }
}
mysqli_close($conn);
```